# component dropdown flicker when state is updated

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, antd, react-dnd

I have a table where I can drag my row item into a folder. The data in the table will keep updating every 5 seconds in order to get the updated data. Every row has a dropdown button and link. My problem is when I mouseover to a dropdown button on a row, the dropdown menu will flicker once the table has completed fetching new data. I would like the dropdown to be  visible and the row when it is mouseover is not flickered when data is updated.

I implemented React.memo, but seems like it doesnt help.

This is my sample source code: stackblitz.com/edit/react-w1bbuc-6uucs7

Would really appreciate if somebody can help to figure out the main issue.